# Difference between approches for setting DefaultStyleKey

Tags: .net, wpf, themes, custom-controls, resourcedictionary

I am creating a custom control(deriving from `Control`) and want to define a default theme for the control. Previously all the custom controls I created, I have used

```
static IntegerUpDown()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(IntegerUpDown), 
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(IntegerUpDown)));
}
```

with this `assembly` attribute:

```
[assembly: ThemeInfo(ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly,
ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly)]
```

Alternative approach to do this is (which I have also noticed in some controls) -

```
public IntegerUpDown()
{
    DefaultStyleKey = typeof(IntegerUpDown);
}
```

I would like to know the pros and cons of these two approaches and which one to prefer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can observe that the first approach asks the dependency property framework to register a default style key. It does that only once (being in a static constructor) and then onwards it is used for all instances of `IntegerUpDown`. Second approach assignes the Key explicitly when an instance of `IntegerUpDown` is created on its own. They both seem ok to me.

MSDN says ...

> Metadata can be overriden so that subclasses can tweak a DP by
>   overriding the property’s metadata, instead of completely
>   re-implementing the property itself.