# Style of TextBox causes exception when loading control in other assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary, mergeddictionaries

I have created an assembly for reusable controls (amongst other things). In this assembly, there is a Themes/Generic.xaml file that is used for custom control styles.
I would like to implement the different styles for different controls in separate files, so I thought that it would be a good idea to use a merged dictionary.

My Generic/Themes.xaml looks like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="../Resources/MyTextBoxStyle.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The file MyTextBoxStyle.xaml looks like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:general="clr-namespace:com.testsoft.General">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type general:MyTextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I have added a static constructor so the style will be applied:

```
static MyTextBox()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyTextBox)));
}
```

When using this custom TextBox in another assembly, the application crashes with the following exception:

`IOException: Die Ressource "resources/mytextboxstyle.xaml" kann nicht gefunden werden.`
(the resource could not be found)

However, if I do not use the MergedDictionary approach and add all of the style XAML directly into the Generic/Themes.xaml file, everything works fine.

I tried to change the Build Action of the MyTextBoxStyle.xaml file to Resource, Embedded Resource but that didn't help.
How can I use MergedDictionaries and still be able to use the styled control in other assemblies?

Comment: why do you want to apply the style in code in the first place?
thats against MVVM...

Comment: Otherwise the style won't be applied. What is the MVVM way of doing this?

Comment: that depends on what you want to do...
if you are adding the textbox you created in code to your view you are kind of breaking the roules already. Normally you would use an items control and bind its source to an observable collection and tell it how to display the given data.
Maybe if you explain to me what you are doing in a bigger scope i can help out

Comment: I have created a custom TextBox. The TextBox is used in another project (it will be added with XAML). The TextBox offers a new property. My model class is bound to this property, so I am pretty sure that I do not violate the MVVM pattern here.

Comment: if you just use it in code why dont you do it like this:
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}"/>  ?

MVVM means, beside other thing to seperate the code executed from the view beeing displayed and you are changing the design/behaviour of your view in you code. Unless i am missing something here thats not the exact use of the pattern...

Comment: Because both the style and the TextBox are implemented in another assembly. I want the style to be applied automatically (I don't want the developer to be forced to apply the style manually).

Answer (score 1):

I do exactly the same thing as you want to. Create a `FrameworkLibrary` and use it on every `customerSolution`. If I define a `DefaultStyleKey` I use the uncommented procedure. I don't know if you get better perfomance on static constructor. In your `CustomerApplication (Testbase)` you only have to link your `Themes.xaml` inside of the `App.xaml`.

### Control Library (WpfControlLibrary1)

```cs
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfControlLibrary1
{
    public class MyTextBox : TextBox
    {
        static MyTextBox()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyTextBox)));
        }

        //public MyTextBox()
        //{
        //    DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyTextBox);
        //}
    }
}
```

- [Difference between approches for setting DefaultStyleKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646838/difference-between-approches-for-setting-defaultstylekey)

### Testapplication (Testbase)

**App.xaml**

```xml
<Application x:Class="Testbase.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Testbase"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
         <ResourceDictionary>
             <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                 <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfControlLibrary1;component/generic/Themes.xaml" />
             </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
         </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have done the exact same steps, I don't get any compile errors (or "curly" lines"), so everything is found. When I start the app, it still crashes...same exception. Even if I add the MyTextBoxStyle.xaml instead of the Themes/Generic.xaml. I double checked with the Reflector and the file is in the Resources folder of the assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Is this in your new assembly? `xmlns:general="clr-namespace:com.testsoft.General"`
If that namespace doesn't exist then maybe remove it from the xaml.

Also if it is a resource you may have to access it through something like `<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://,,,Resources/MyTextBoxStyle.xaml" />`

I cannot remember the precise method, so the above is a massive generalisation.

Also have you actually included the WPFLibrary as a resource on the testbase project? because if not then there's your issue, it's not including the mytextbox in your wpf project as a dll and so it cannot load the resource from the project.

Comment: This results in the same exception.

Comment: Did you use it exactly? Because it wasn't an acurrate depiction of the code that should be used.

Comment: Please check the addition to the answer here, I think this may be what needs checking next.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute path to your resource identified by assembly (replace `WpfCustomControlLibrary1` with assembly name of your custom control library).

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfCustomControlLibrary1;component/Resources/MyTextBoxStyle.xaml" />
```

Comment: It works for me in a sample project. It looks like you have something non-standard. Make sure your TextBoxStyle.xaml is in correct place and is marked as a Page

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by adjusting the url to this:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/ControlFramework.Wpf;component/Resources/MyPathTextBox.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Now everything works as expected (style is being applied and no exception is thrown).

Comment: oh ok, out of curiosity what was the namespace used for your library?